# Is Assembly.Load(byte[]) not thread safe?

Tags: .net, assemblies

I am attaching to the [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwdd50tz%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event and then calling [Assembly.Load(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h538bck7.aspx) to load the assembly.

It seems that if this is done from multiple Threads I can end up with duplicate assemblies loaded. However if I call [Assembly.LoadFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) or [Assembly.LoadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b61s44e8.aspx) this problem does not occur.

I was just wondering if this is a known qwerk of using Assembly.Load? Is it not thread safe and I need to add extra code to handle this scenario?

Full code follows...

```
[TestFixture]
public class Tester
{
    [Test]
    public void Run()
    {
        var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += ResolveAssembly;

        var thread1 = new Thread(LoadAssembly);
        var thread2 = new Thread(LoadAssembly);

        thread1.Start();
        thread2.Start();
        thread1.Join();
        thread2.Join();
        var assemblies = currentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        Assert.AreEqual(1, assemblies.Count(x => x.GetName().Name == "AssemblyToReference"));
    }

    Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        //This works
        //return Assembly.LoadFile(@"PathToAssembly");

        //This works
        //return Assembly.LoadFrom(@"PathToAssembly");

        //This does not work
        return Assembly.Load(File.ReadAllBytes(@"PathToAssembly"));
    }

    void LoadAssembly()
    {
        Assembly.Load("AssemblyToReference");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looking at the implementation details of these methods you can make the case that the LoadFrom and LoadFile methods, since they are using the filesystem, have their synchronization there. That is, both methods get an exclusive lock on the file prior to reading it in. This of course is not the case with the assembly residing in memory.

(And MSDN has no statement of these methods being thread safe, perhaps that says enough? :))

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx mentions that the type (Assembly) is thread-safe. So that would indicate the entire type, including Assembly.Load(byte[]) is indeed thread safe.

Comment: "thread safe" is a rather meaningless term since very little documentation says what the "safe" behavior is going to be. Sometimes, "thread safe" only means "doesn't crash when access from multiple threads" but we almost always require more knowledge about the behavior. Perhaps it is safe to load an assembly from a byte array, given that you sometimes will then get duplicates, but *never a crash*, and this is what the documentation means. Typically only "concurrent" data structure classes document what the safe behavior is going to be.

Comment: Lasse, in my scenario I load different assemblies from a concurrent scenario. Thread safe is not a meaningless term at all. I can account for and verify other variables. If indeed it was not thread safe, then I'd have to maintain a thread-safe collection from an asynchronous read operation, add the byte arrays to it, and then loop over this, adding in the assemblies one by one.

Answer (score 2):

Documentation does indicate that loading the same assembly multiple times may result in copies/new instances, so I definitely would avoid calling it twice on the same assembly, or on different versions of an assembly.

Aside this, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly(v=vs.110).aspx mentions that the type (Assembly) is thread-safe. So that would indicate the entire type, including Assembly.Load(byte[]) is indeed thread safe.

Given earier information in this topic, I feel the need to **define** thread safe (as per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety#Levels_of_thread_safety)):

- Thread safe: Implementation is guaranteed to be free of race conditions when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously.

This means that you can safely use it from multiple threads, but you should be aware that the operation is not **[idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)**; calling it twice leave you with two results, rather than one.

Conceptually, if the above is a problem, the code that *uses* Assembly.Load(byte[]) is in fact not thread safe.